# Excel MATCH returns incorrect value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please take a look at this Excel screenshot:

[image]

Cell `A1` has formula `=MATCH("ASNA Adj Net Sales",B:B)`. I expect this formula to return `3`, but it returns `1`. Why?

Even stranger: if the value in cell `B2` is deleted, then the result in cell `A1` changes to the (expected) value `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `=MATCH("ASNA Adj Net Sales",B:B,0)`. You are missing the `match_type`.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a

Comment: This is crazy that match_type=0 (exact) isn't the default value.